# Converting ROW values to Column values in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

SQL server 2008 Query for converting below Existing table to Expected output

Existing Table

```
Name    Area    SubArea Value1  Value2  Value3  Value4  Value5  Value6
Sam     UK      UK      1       2       3               5       6
```

Expecting output:

```
Name    Area    SubArea Value
Sam     UK      UK      1
Sam     UK      UK      2
Sam     UK      UK      3
Sam     UK      UK  
Sam     UK      UK      5
Sam     UK      UK      6
```

Comment: So, what you tried? Please add description

Comment: SELECT   Name,Area,Subarea,Values ,ColumnValues
FROM [dbo].[ExisitingTable]
UNPIVOT
(
       ColumnValues
    FOR [Values] IN ([Value1], [Value2], [Value3],[value4], [value5], [value6])
) AS P

Comment: Got worked out successfully from above Query..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use `apply` :

```
select t.Name, t.Area, t.SubArea, tt.Value
from table t cross apply
     ( values (Value1), (Value2), (Value3), (Value4), (Value5), (Value6)
     ) tt(Value);
```